# Does WordPress $wpdb functions wait when table is locked?

Tags: database, wpdb

Does WordPress' `$wpdb` functions wait when the table is locked?

For example Function A() uses `$wpdb->getresults`. When  `$wpdb->getresults` wants to read a table and its locked, does it wait for unlocking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By itself `wodb` doesn't do (and probably can't) anything extra to what the DB will do. When the table is locked you will probably wait longer for a response or fail on timeout.

Comment: It seems it just trys to recconect to db only when connection is lost.Thanks